# Proving linear transformation and that T is the differential operator

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I have two problems that are pretty short. I understand the concepts behind, however I am not sure if my proofs are insufficient:

1. Determine whether $T: M_{nn}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $T(A)=a_{11}a_{22}\cdots a_{nn}$ is a linear transformation.

Let $A = (a_{nn})$ and $B = (b_{nn})$.
So, $$T(kA + wB) = (k(a_{11}a_{22}\cdots a_{nn}) + w(b_{11}b_{22}\cdots b_{nn}))$$
which is 
$$k(a_{11}a_{22}\cdots a_{nn}) + w(b_{11}b_{22}\cdots b_{nn})$$
and thus
$$kT(A) + wT(B)$$
so we have a linear transformation since we have closure under addition and scalar multiplication.

2. Let $T: \mathcal{P}_n \to \mathcal{P}_n$ be a linear transformation such that $T(x^k) = kx^{k-1}$ for $k=0,1,\dots,n$. Show that $T$ must be the differential operator $D$.

We observe that 
$$D(cx^k+ wy^k) = ckx^{k-1} +  wky^{k-1}$$
which is $$ cD(x^k)+ wD(y^k) = cT(x^k) + wT(y^k)$$
Thus T is the differential operator D.

Thanks!

Comment: $T(kA+wB) = (ka_{11}+wb_{11})(ka_{22}+wb_{22})\dots (ka_{nn}+wb_{nn})$.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof of the first statement is wrong. Take a $2 \times 2$ matrix consisting of all $1$s, call it $A$. Then $T(A) = 1^4 = 1$. But $T(A+A) = 2^4 = 16 \neq T(A) + T(A)$

Your proof of 2 is also not correct. You want to show that for any polynominal $p(x)$, that $$T(p(x)) = Dp(x) = \frac{d \ }{dx} p(x)$$

Comment: I'm not really sure how I'd do that. Is it as simple as saying D of some p(x) is d/dx p(x), which is T(p(x))?